# CordovaFile & CordovaFileTransfer. How get correct name of file, with correct type file

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I have a project that loads the files from site. In the browser, click a link (http://www.uzhnu.edu.ua/uk/infocentre/get/6500), it loads files at once with сorrectly name and extension. How to implement it in the ionic app, I do not know. 
File downloaded from url, where $scope.id is id of file (etc. 6500)
Help me please, or give some ideas how solve this.

```
$scope.downloadFile = function() {
$ionicLoading.show({template: 'Download file...'});
var url = "http://www.uzhnu.edu.ua/uk/infocentre/get/"+$scope.id; 
var filename = $scope.id+".doc";
alert(filename);
var targetPath = "/storage/sdcard0/documents/" + filename;
var trustHosts = true
var options = {};
$cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
.then(function() {
// Success!
$ionicLoading.hide();
alert('File download ' + targetPath);
}, function(error) {
$ionicLoading.hide();
// An error occured. Show a message to the user
alert('Sorry');
alert(JSON.stringify(error));
});
};
```

Comment: $scope.id is scope variable please check here http://santoshshinde2012.blogspot.in/2015/03/file-upload-download-with-ng-cordova.html

Comment: i watch this tutorial, but problem is in my url there is no  "file name" only id

Comment: I update the answer please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES! Finally I did it!If someone will need a code, here it is:

```
 $scope.downloadFile = function() {
    var url = "http://example.com/page";
    $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Download file...'});
    $http.get(url).
      success(function (data, status, headers) {
        var head = headers('Content-Disposition');
        var filename = head.substr(head.lastIndexOf('=')+1);
        alert(filename);
        var targetPath = "/storage/sdcard0/documents/" + filename;
        var trustHosts = true;
        var options = {};
        $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
          .then(function(entry) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
            alert('File download: ' + targetPath);
          }, function(error) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            console.log('headers: ' + headers('Cache-Control'));
            // An error occured. Show a message to the user
            alert('Sorry');
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
          })
        alert(head1);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
        return(JSON.stringify(head1))
      })
      .error(function (status) {
        alert(status);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function to download file from server

Pass the parameter to function *document_filename* and use it on the place of  *$scope.id*

```
        $scope.downloadFile = function(document_filename) {
            $ionicLoading.show({
                template: 'Download file...'
            });
            var url = "http://www.uzhnu.edu.ua/uk/infocentre/get/" + document_filename;
            var filename = document_filename + ".doc";
            alert(filename);
            var targetPath = "/storage/sdcard0/documents/" + filename;
            var trustHosts = true
            var options = {};
            $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
                .then(function() {
                    // Success!
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    alert('File download ' + targetPath);
                }, function(error) {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    // An error occured. Show a message to the user
                    alert('Sorry');
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                });
        };
```

Hope this will help you !!

And for more details go to [here](http://santoshshinde2012.blogspot.in/2015/03/file-upload-download-with-ng-cordova.html).

Comment: File downloaded with name "Undefided.doc", but in website is another file (pdf, jpg, etc).
I think maybe problems in headers. In "Postman" displayed correct name of file, but have parse this data i don't know. 
Here is [screen](http://prntscr.com/as3xt7)

Comment: please pass the your file name at the time of calling function like downloadFile(6500)

Comment: I do not really understand about what you write. It is possible more in detail?
Right now in Postman I found in Headers that conveys the file name(**Content-Disposition → inline;filename=02121128_variant.doc**), but as it is inserted into the document, I do not know

Comment: please create simple codepen or add your view code for more details

Comment: I have an example, but it has the same problems as in my application
+ Download files can only be emulator or real device

http://codepen.io/Serjonka/pen/yObRQL

Comment: mean you face the problem in emulator

Comment: The problem is not in the download file. The problem of correctly displaying data. I also have not decided yet.
I upload my project into github, of you can help please watch:
https://github.com/banhaserhij/FIT

Comment: what exactly problem you are facing ?

Comment: you got error like Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.uzhnu.edu.ua/uk/infocentre/openApi/48. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS

Comment: are you run application in browser or device ?

Comment: and file transfer plugin run in only device not in browser

Comment: The problem is that I can not properly display the data on the view. Json format that I get is important for the data to me. This is id, caption, item_type and items. File downloads, and rolling on id. Caption displays the name if file or folder. Item_type said that if the type of file, you need to download it. If a folder type, you need to either open accordion list (provided that there is data in the items parameter. Either open a new view)

Comment: I run app on real device and his work, only download file with wrong name

Comment: "what exactly problem you are facing?"
Now I have an application that can only download the desired file if the id is displayed in the header application (which is not the case with navigation) I mean if іd folder 168, i it has a file with the id 6500 if I click on the download button, it loads the file with the id 168, rather than 6500. Only when I turn on file with the id 6500 if can download file

Comment: In browser i only watch `alert(filename);` a file name, that I am downloading